# rosdep install of libyaml-cpp-dev fails

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I have a package with the following dependency:

```
<depend>libyaml-cpp-dev</depend>
```

When I try to run the `rosdep install mypackage` command, I would expect that apt installs the `libyaml-cpp-dev` package. However, I get the following error instead:

```
Cannot locate rosdep definition for [libyaml-cpp-dev]
```

Any idea why rosdep fails in this case? Thx!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390962/rosdep-install-of-libyaml-cpp-dev-fails/) by [ticotico](https://answers.ros.org/users/58821/ticotico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 212 on 2021-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're using the debian package name not the rosdep key for this package.

If you look it up in the rules you'll see that that debian package corresponds to `yaml-cpp`

https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/dc95e3e9e7ff78fa8cc4f0f9c5396dd0672ad7a2/rosdep/base.yaml#L7940-L7983

You should use that key and rosdep will resolve it to `libyaml-cpp-dev` on Ubuntu as well different package names like `libyaml-cpp-devel` for Fedora. We current best practice is to use the debian package name however it's not guaranteed. And we don't change existing keys to avoid breaking existing users.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2021-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ticotico](https://answers.ros.org/users/58821/ticotico/) on 2021-11-15**:
perfect, thx a lot for that lightning-fast answer! Some background info: [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/84616/help-understanding-system-and-package-dependencies-with-rosbuild-and-catkin/?answer=84621#post-id-84621)